# Is EventCollection obsolete?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm going through this tutorial: http://mwop.net/blog/266-Using-the-ZF2-EventManager.html about ZF2's event manager and it references an EventCollection, which I cannot locate on my framework. Have they changed this feature since the article was written?

Answer (score 1):

EventCollection object has been replaced with EventManagerInterface in ZF2. But it exists in its backported version in 1.12. The article you mentioned is a year old. Check http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/an-introduction-to-zendeventmanager/ and the manual for updates.